# Unable to understand few statements from ASP.NET Core ebook

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have recently started learning ASP.NET Core with the help of an ebook. There are few statements mentioned in the initial chapters, which I am unable to understand clearly.

For eg. following statements are mentioned under **Foundational improvements in ASP.NET Core** section

1. Lightweight and modular HTTP request pipeline
2. Ships entirely as NuGet packages including the runtime
3. Runtime can be installed Side-by-side- allows you to version application along with runime

The above statements are not clear to me probably because of the term *"modular HTTP request pipeline"* from **Point 1** and terms *"runtime"* and *"version application"* from **Point 2**.

Any short explanation or reference to the suitable doc will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### http request pipeline

They totally rebuild the `HttpListener` which is also called the http server. Normally you would host your application in iis which would give you tons of functions but is 1 very old, massive sluggish application.

Now on default you run the application as a console which starts up a `HttpListener` which is called [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) in dotnet core.

This kestrel is totally build from the ground up (so modular priciples and barely any technical depth). And is build based on a very vast C++ library called libuv.

The modularity in this means that it has been build in various loosly coupled parts, meaning that you could replace or extend those parts if you want to. For example use a [test server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) for automatic integration tests.

### Ships in nuget packages

Normally you would install a netFramework eg: 4.5.0 and you would already get all these system.* dlls eg: System.web.dll

Now all these dll's are nuget packages and bundled into 1 package called netstandard: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/.

### Multiple runtimes

If you build a dotnet project, it creates Dlls. these dlls can be run by by any OS if that os has installed the dotnet runtime. (basicaly dll is intermediate language and can be run by the dotnet runtime).

You can also build your dotnet project to **include** the runtime inside your application, so you can run multiple dotnet applications on an OS with different Dotnet runtime versions.

The downside of this last option is that you have to build your dotnet project for every OS specifically. So normally people choose to just build the OS independent Dlls and make sure the right runtime is installed on the OS.

Comment: Hi @Joel, I understand that:

1. In .NET Core, Kestrel is the web server which processes our request and provides us with a response. 
2. By "version application along with runime" means keeping multiple copies of application each including runtime means to target expected number of Operation Systems.

Still, I am unclear about what HTTP request pipeline actually consists of in terms of NET Core?

Comment: @user3747423 its basically a (newer) version of the OWIN middleware pipeline

Comment: Well, that just touch over my head :). So request pipeline actually consists of middlewares which can be responsible for processing Request and Response (for certain reasons). Please correct me, If I am wrong.

Comment: yes you can inject parts into the pipeline called middleware, these can handle the request or give the request to the next middleware in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig more into this concept. I think I got all my queries resolved for now at least.

Comment: @user3747423 if you really want to learn how these things works. you can just download their source code, looking though there will give you a lot more indepth insight: https://github.com/aspnet